# Express query fails with integers

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, request, endpoint

I'm running an Express server to create endpoints out of a MongoDB which I'm basing on this guide https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mean-apps-restful-api

In attempting to define query strings I have the following function:

```
app.get("/contacts", function(req, res) {
  db.collection(CONTACTS_COLLECTION).find(req.query).toArray(function(err, docs) {
      res.status(200).json(docs);  
  });
});
```

This works as expected for using queries where the query parameter is a string e.g. `/contacts?name=Bob`. However, if the field I'm querying happens to be an integer (e.g. using the query `/contacts?age=21`), I find that the response produces an empty array... []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every thing is came in request query is string so if you set your url with age=21 then you have to parse it into integer.

```
app.get("/contacts", function(req, res) {
   var condition = {};
  if(req.query.age) {
    condition.age = parseInt(req.query.age, 10);
  }
  db.collection(CONTACTS_COLLECTION).find(condition).toArray(function(err, docs) {
      res.status(200).json(docs);  
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Negate that. http requests interpret everything as strings.

I found the solution in the [express-query-int package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-query-int)